# Ginzburg-Landau integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, superconductivity

My question is exactly the same as [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/170352/how-is-the-current-equation-calculated-from-ginzburg-landau-gl-free-energy), but I cannot do the variation of integral referred in the **Addendum**, i.e.,
\begin{align}
S_B\propto\int dx\; B^2=\int \left(\nabla\times A\right)^2\; dx,
\end{align}
where $S_B$ is some magnetic action, $B$ the magnetic field and $A$ the vector potential. I have problems when I vary wrt $A$. I don't obtain the last equality:
\begin{align}
\delta S_B\propto 2\int dx\;\left[\left(\nabla\times A\right)\cdot \left(\nabla\times\delta A\right)\right]=2\left[\delta A\times (\nabla\times A)\right]+2\int dx\; \left[(\nabla\times\nabla\times A)\cdot \delta A\right].
\end{align}

Comment: Did you already derived the Euler-Lagrange equations ? It's the same thing here. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Lagrange_equation and references therein.

Comment: I think my question was not well defined. I know to derive E-L equations, and I understand I have to vary with respect to $A$, but I cannot obtain the last equality. Maybe is some easy calculation, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the vector calculus identity
$$
\nabla\cdot(\delta {\bf A}\times(\nabla \times {\bf A}))= (\nabla\times \delta{\bf A})\cdot(\nabla\times {\bf A})- \delta {\bf A} \cdot (\nabla\times(\nabla \times {\bf A})),
$$
and Stokes' theorem. Note that you need an extra pair of parenthesis in your last volume integral ---vector products are not associative so what you have written is ambiguous---  and the first term on the RHS should be  a surface integral.