# Free energy term for the magnetic field in Ginzburg-Landau theory

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, superconductivity

The present question is related to this [physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/170352/how-is-the-current-equation-calculated-from-ginzburg-landau-gl-free-energy) post. In Ginzburg-Landau theory, [the free energy of the superconductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginzburg%E2%80%93Landau_theory) can be written as

$$F = F_n + \alpha |\psi|^2 + \frac{\beta}{2} |\psi|^4 + \frac{1}{2m} \left| \left(-i\hbar\nabla - 2e\mathbf{A} \right) \psi \right|^2 + \frac{|\mathbf{B}|^2}{2\mu_0} \;\;\;\;(1).$$
where the first term is a constant serving as a reference value for the free energy, the last terms corresponding to that of the magnetic field. I understand that it comes from the standard expression for the energy of magnetic field. The first term, on the other hand, corresponds the value of the free energy for the normal phase with $\psi=0$ without considering the magnetic field, namely, $F_n=F(\psi=0,\mathbf{B}=0)$.

The thermodynamic equilibrium is obtained by minimizing the free energy. For superconductor phase, we have $T<T_C$ and $\alpha<0$, and therefore it implies $|\psi|^2 = - \frac\alpha \beta$ and there is no magnetic field inside the superconductor, namely, $\mathbf{B}=\nabla\times\mathbf{A}=0$. It can be viewed as a consequence that the corresponding functional derivative with respect to $\mathbf{A}$ gives rise to the London's equation, which in turn suppresses the magnetic field. Also, since $\mathbf{A}$ can be viewed as a free degree of freedom as much as $\psi$ does, $\mathbf{B}=0$ minimizes the free energy, as expected.

On the other hand, for the normal phase, where $T>T_C$ and $\alpha>0$, one finds $\psi=0$. However, it seems that in this case $\mathbf{A}$ is not be determined by minimizing the free energy, as it is known that $\mathbf{B}\ne 0$ but $\mathbf{A}=0$ gives the smallest value. My first question is: the gut feeling is that we probably should be able to carry out functional variation with respect to $\mathbf{A}=0$ to determine the magnetic field, why it seems not to work here?

As discussed in textbook, for instance, *Statistical Mechanics - A Set of Lectures* by Richard Feynman. In a (type I, to be specific) superconducting phase, the magnetic field is pushed out of the superconductor, therefore, work must be carried out against the magnetic pressure by the superconductor during the process. In particular, in the case of critical magnetic field, by equating the Gibbs free energy of the two phase, the Helmholtz free energy of the superconducting phase is smaller than that of normal phase by an amount, since the superconductor has to holding off the magnetic pressure, it is determined by
$$F_{nor}-F_{sup}=\frac{\mathbf{B}_c^2}{2\mu_0}\;\;\;(2)$$
which is essentially (10.1) in the mentioned textbook.

Now, as the two phases are in equilibrium, I understand that the contribution of the magnetic field should be considered in both phases in the above expressions. In other words, it is a normal conductor with the presence of magnetic field in equilibrium with (or in other words, transits to at no cost) a superconductor with the magnetic field expelled. **In this context, the magnetic field is indeed a part of the equilibrated thermalized systems.** Therefore, $F_{nor}$ in Eq.(2) is not exactly the same as $F_n$ in Eq.(1), while the latter is, for the most part, a reference value. Subsequently, Eq.(2) can not be found satisfied. To be more specific, one shall substitute $\psi=0$ and $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{B}_{c}$ in Eq.(1) for the normal phase, and $\mathbf{B}=0$ and $\psi\ne 0$ in Eq.(1) for the superconducting phase. Therefore, we have $$F_{nor}-F_{sup}=F(\psi=0,\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{B}_c)-F(|\psi|^2=-\frac{\alpha}{\beta},\mathbf{B}= 0)>\frac{\mathbf{B}_c^2}{2\mu_0}.$$ 
The resulting contradiction leads to my second question.

What am I missing?

**P.S.**

In fact, I found that in the review paper *M Cyrot 1973 Rep. Prog. Phys. 36 103*, the free energy is written in a different form, c.f. Eq.(8) of the paper. To be specific, there the contribution of the magnetic field reads
$$\frac{1}{8\pi}|H(r)-H_a|^2 .$$
where $H_a$, seemingly not defined in the text, is likely the external magnetic field. I don't see how it is consistent with Eq.(1).

Comment: People usually study the SC to normal phase transition with a fixed external current (or $\mathbf{H}$), instead of fixed magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$, so the energy contribution from magnetic field is not $+\frac{B^2}{8\pi}$, we should add also the contribution from the current, which is proportional to $-\frac{B^2}{4\pi}$. As a result, the magnetic energy in the normal phase is actually negative.

Comment: The possibility for the magnetic field to be expelled from the superconducting phase is already encoded in the Ginzburg-Landau formalism you gave. Minimising the free energy, you would get the London equation for instance, see e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/170352/16689  If you had defined correctly the different terms, you would have noticed that you missed the contribution of the normal part to the free energy, namely $F=F_n + F_s + F_B$ where $F_n$ is the free energy of the normal metal (you can let it unknown), $F_s$ is the free energy of the superconducting state, and (...)

Comment: (...) $F_B$ is the energy of the magnetic field, which is the last term in your expression for $F$. You can not understand how the superconducting state is destroyed by a magnetic field towards a normal metal if you simply forbid this possibility in your model ! Also, your notation (completely ill-defined to start with) change in the middle of your question. Please be a little bit more serious when asking for help.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! @ChuanChen Would you please provide a reference or an answer?

Comment: @FraSchelle Thanks for the hint! But I am even more confused. I understand that the notion of free energy in Landau's second order phase transition implies that the minimum of the free energy describes both phases in question, it can be either the normal phase (when $\alpha>0$) or the superconducting phase (when $\alpha<0$), and the transition occurs when the two continuously merges. So why sum them up? Please consider write an answer.

Comment: @FraSchelle I updated the question. Please take a look. Many thanks!

Comment: @gamebm Many standard textbooks on superconductivity have discussed this issue (especially when discussing the critical field). One example is [the book by Tinkham](https://books.google.com.sg/books/about/Introduction_to_Superconductivity.html?id=k6AO9nRYbioC&redir_esc=y).