# Derivation of current equation from Ginzburg-Landau Theory

Tags: superconductivity

I am trying to derive GL current equation and am not sure how to do the operation.
The answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/170352/how-is-the-current-equation-calculated-from-ginzburg-landau-gl-free-energy) has the math that is beyond me and non SI unit confuse me. So, I post my question here.

$$\frac{\partial g_s}{\partial A} = \frac{\partial}{\partial A} \frac{1}{2m}  \vert (\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla - qA)\psi \vert^2 $$

The expected result:
$$ j_s = \frac{\partial g_s}{\partial A} = \frac{q\hbar}{i2m} (\psi^*\nabla\psi - \psi\nabla\psi^*) - \frac{q^2}{m}A|\psi|^2) $$

Ignoring the absolute operation. Thinkam and Schmidt do not use absolute value, while Buckel-Kleiner use.

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial g_s}{\partial A} & = \frac{1}{2m}  2 (\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla\psi - qA\psi)(-q\psi) \\
& = \frac{-q}{m} (\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla\psi - qA\psi)(\psi) \\
& = \frac{-q}{m} (\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla\psi^*\psi - qA\psi^*\psi) \\
& = -\frac{q\hbar}{im} (\psi^*\nabla\psi - \psi\nabla\psi^*) + \frac{q^2}{m}A|\psi|^2) \\
\end{align}

I am not sure in the 3rd and 4th line and the sign of the result is not correct.

1. How to do the operation actually in this ?
2. I do not think $(\psi)(\psi) = \psi^*\psi = |\psi|$ but that is the closest form that I got and still the sign is wrong. what should I do if I come across this operation, a wave function (order parameter) multiplied by itself?

I am aware this is more a math question. If I need to move it to Math SE, let me know.

EDIT:
other attempt. following Thinkam, the $\psi$ is not squared. still not sure because the sign is not correct as well.
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial g_s}{\partial A} & = \frac{\partial}{\partial A} \frac{1}{2m}   (\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla - qA)^2 \vert\psi\vert \\
& = \frac{1}{2m} \frac{\partial}{\partial A} (-\hbar^2\nabla^2 - 2\frac{\hbar}{i}qA\nabla + q^2A^2) \vert\psi\vert\\
& = \frac{1}{2m} (- 2\frac{\hbar}{i}q\nabla + q^2A) \vert\psi\vert \\
& = \frac{-q}{m} (\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla\psi^*\psi - qA\psi^*\psi) \\
& = -\frac{q\hbar}{im} (\psi^*\nabla\psi - \psi\nabla\psi^*) + \frac{q^2}{m}A|\psi|^2) \\
\end{align}